# Why is the swap function not working correctly in quick sort?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find an error why quicksort does not work properly, I guess it is because of the swap function

```
function swap(a, b) {
    return [b,a];
}

function partition(array, l, r) {
    let pivot = array[(l + r) / 2];
    let i = l;
    let j = r;

    while (i <= j) {
        while (array[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (array[j] > pivot)
            j++;
        if(i >= j)
            return j;
        [array[i], array[j]] = swap([array[i]], array[j]);
    }
}

function qsort(arr, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        let q = partition(arr, left, right)
        qsort(arr, left, q);
        qsort(arr, q + 1, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: the swap function is pass by value. it's a copy of original values., so swapping isn't gonna do the trick, you can pass an array and then the two indexes, then swap them in that func.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass as a separated variable in swap function

```
[array[i], array[j]] = swap(array[i], array[j]);
```

correct solution will be

```
function swap(array, i, j) {
    temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

// call it like this
swap(array, index1, index2);
```

Comment: Fixed the function, but the question arose why the loop while(i <= j) is infinite

Comment: @RumeOne I think when array element value is equal to pivot you are not incrementing i&j that might be the case where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

`swap` does have a problem, at least it should be `swap(array[i], array[j])` instead of `swap([array[i]], array[j])`. but I think your sorting problem Not here, maybe you can try the following

```js
function partition(array, l, r) {
    let pivot = array[l];
    let i = l;
    let j = r;

    while (i < j) {
        while (i < j && array[j] >= pivot) --j;
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        while (i < j && array[i] <= pivot) i++;
        arr[j] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[i] = pivot;
    return i;
}

function qsort(arr, left, right) {
    if (left < right) {
        let q = partition(arr, left, right)
        qsort(arr, left, q-1);
        qsort(arr, q + 1, right);
    }
}

const arr = [1, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 6, 0, 5, 4];
qsort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
console.log(arr); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```